# Can't access string in <a> tag in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab the  tags from html table using the code below:

```
url = "https://www.worldfootball.net/report/premier-league-2007-2008-arsenal-fc-fulham-fc/"
url_content=requests.get(url).content
match_content = BeautifulSoup(url_content,'html.parser')
tag = match_content.find_all(class_="standard_tabelle")
#Get teams
teams = tag[0].find_all("a")
#Iterate through goals
for a in tag[1].select("tr"):
    b = a.select_one("a")
    print(b)
```

If I 'print' the result I get:

```
None
<a href="/player_summary/david-healy/" title="David Healy">David Healy</a>
<a href="/player_summary/robin-van-persie/" title="Robin van Persie">Robin van Persie</a>
<a href="/player_summary/aliaksandr-hleb/" title="Aliaksandr Hleb">Aliaksandr Hleb</a>
```

but if I try to print 'b.string' I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

I appreciate my code probably isn't the most robust but I can't fathom why it won't grab the string from each result. Any help would be appreciated. 
Many thanks

Comment: The first row doesn't have an `a` tag... so you only want to print the text when there is one... `if b is not None: print(b.string)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `<tr>` returned by `tag[1].select("tr")` has no `<a>` in it. You can see that when `print(b)` prints `None`. But then you try to use that to get the `string` attribute, which doesn't work. Check that `b` actually contains something:

```
if b:
    print(b.string)
```